# onOffsetChanged listener resize/relocate ...redraw causes laggy scroll

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and within I resize and move views on collapse/uncollapse using `ConstraintLayout`

```
appbar.onOffsetChanged { appBarLayout, verticalOffset -> 
    //... do math
    aConstrainedView.requestLayout()
}
```

The problem comes that the scroll starts to lag big time because of `requestLayout()` redrawing the whole hierarchy.

Is there some optimizing or any other sufficient way to modify views following the scroll in that Situation?

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarCL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <ImageView />

            <ImageView />

            <View />

            <View/>

            <ImageView />

            <ImageView />

            <TextView />

            <TextView />


            <GridLayout>

                <TextView />

                <TextView />

                <TextView />

                <TextView />

            </GridLayout>

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline />

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline/>

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline />

      </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>>


  </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Just change position of the views the way you want and don't call `requestLayout()`. Calling it is expensive and shouldn't be done here.

Comment: If you only need to change offset use translationX / Y, it's much faster and doesn't affect layout calls.